# Included jtds---.jar file into the libraries of my Java Project on NetBeans, but still having a ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase, classnotfoundexception

This is my first question here, and, for some reason, when trying to upload a screenshot of my problem, I got an error message which read
*Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur*

Anyway, I have uploaded it onto Google Photos, so I will send the link after explaining a little what it is.

I am new to developping Apps in Java, specially when it is about connecting to JDBC. So, as the target database is a SyBase one, I downloaded JTDS JDBC Driver from its official website on sourceforge

Afterwards I did what was suggested [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.be/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html) so as to set up the class path.

Include jtds1.3.1 into the library and my project, so it was supposed to work, and... voilà!

A fantastic ClassNotFoundException when executing the Class.forName() method to load the driver.

[Here](http://bit.ly/14wMVip) is the screenshot, being lines 35 and 37 the ones of interest.

I would be so grateful should someone help me a little, however stupid may be the error I may be doing to have this problem - which sure it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at that screenshot, the problem is that you added the distribution zip (`jtds-1.3.1-dist.zip`) to your buildpath, instead of the `jtds-1.3.1.jar` included in that zip. So unzip, remove the zip from the build-path and add the `jar`-file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the full path to the jarfile in the classpath (including the filename):

```
.;C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre\lib;
C:\Program Files\mysql-connector-java-3.1.144\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar
```

after change path once restart your cmd

Comment: Question is about the buildpath/classpath as in the IDE not commandline use.